# Matlab (ANFIS) Error in training

Tags: matlab, artificial-intelligence, fuzzy-logic

I have a Sugeno 2-input - 1-output fuzzy system with 5mfs per rule and 5mfs for the output. However, whenever I am trying to train it, i receive the following error:

[image]

As you may see, the number of rules and the number of output membership functions is the same. I am also posting the console output below.

```
ANFIS info: 
Number of nodes: 23
Number of linear parameters: 9
Number of nonlinear parameters: 12
Total number of parameters: 21
Number of training data pairs: 2084
Number of checking data pairs: 0
Number of fuzzy rules: 3


Start training ANFIS ...

   1     0.0163803
   2     0.0163785

Designated epoch number reached --> ANFIS training completed at epoch 2.

Too many outputs requested.  Most likely cause is missing [] around left hand side that has a comma
separated list expansion.

Error in fisgui (line 91)
        name=nameList{currGui};

Error in mfedit (line 669)
        fisgui #findgui

Error in mfedit (line 602)
            mfedit #selectvar

Error in mfdlg (line 296)
    mfedit('#update',varType,varIndex)

Error using waitfor
Error while evaluating DestroyedObject Callback
```

I am relatively new to Matlab, so I am terribly sorry if I asked something trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out that unfortunately you can't have the same consequent for different antecedents in order to train a fuzzy system; and I had such rules. However, this is very inconvenient when you want to train a fuzzy set with many input membership functions.